# named parameter to npm run script

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, npm, run-script

I would like to pass a named parameter to an npm run script so I can do something like the following:

```
"scripts":{
    "say-hello":"echo $greeting && ls"
 }

 npm run hello --greeting=hello
```

I'd like it to then put 'hello' in place of the $greeting variable, echo the command and then do the ls (this is obviously just a simple example of a chained command)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just found out that this works:

```
"scripts":{
  "say-hello" : "echo $npm_config_greeting && ls"
}
```

**Edit:**

Any environment variables that start with **npm_config_** will be interpreted as a configuration parameter. For example, putting **npm_config_foo=bar** in your environment will set the ***foo*** configuration parameter to ***bar***.

[npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#environment-variables)

Comment: How did you get this to work? I'm trying and I can't figure it out.

Comment: @JacobMiki [here's](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/12bb84f9cb4eed0d1da7) a minimal `package.json`, call with `npm run say-hello --greeting="hello world"` (`npm@2.11.2`)

Comment: That's what I did, and still I get `$npm_config_greeting` echoed. Problem was, that I tried it on Windows and despite running it in bash, echo still expected variable to be in form `%npm_config_greeting%`. I'll delete my answer, as it is wrong.

Comment: @JacobMiki oh right, Windows works differently when it comes to environment variables (which these are). Good point.

Comment: @robertklep do you know if there's any work around or options for windows?

Comment: @Ben sorry, no, I don't have Windows myself so can't check for an alternative.

Comment: In case anybody else is stuck with this - the only way I could get it to work with powershell (pwsh specifically) is to use `$env:variable` where variable is `npm_config_{name of variable passed to script as argument}` .  Strangely obtuse.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to simply add the following '--' followed by your desired param(s). This would be for named parameters that '=' a value. Please note the underlying process in this example, a protractor call, expects a Url arg.

```
npm run e2e -- --Url="https://yoururlhere.com"
```