# npm config parameter on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, cross-platform

I previously asked (and got a great answer for) this question: [named parameter to npm run script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863828/named-parameter-to-npm-run-script)

As mentioned in 1 of the comments to the correct answer, the $npm_config_variable does not work on windows.  I'm looking for a cross platform way to run this script as `npm run say-hello --greeting='hello'`.

Is there any way to check for the OS in npm scripts and use %% instead of $?

Answer (score 0):

Use [minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist) library. Its realy easy to access command line params with it and it works in every environment.

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
var param = argv.param;

// package.json snippet
"scripts": {
   "start": "app --param=value"
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work inside of package.json though.  I need to parse the args in side of the script like this:

"scripts":{
    "start":"echo $NPM_CONFIG_PARAM"
}

then from a command line:
run npm run start --param='hello'